# C# Static Indexer Should Not Compile, but Does

Tags: c#, static, indexer

I realize we cannot have static indexers in C#. But the why does the code below compile correctly (under C# 4.0)?

Since Fred is a static class, it cannot even be instantiated. The declared static indexer makes no sense yet the compiler allows it. Why? I can't imagine it's a compiler bug this late into the language.

```
public static class Fred {
  public static int this[String str] {
    get {
      if (str != null)
        return str.Length;

      return -1;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't compile for me in 4.0.

Comment: "'Fred.this[string]': cannot declare indexers in a static class" and "The modifier 'static' is not valid for this item".

Answer (score 1):

This does not compile.  During compilation, Visual Studio reports 2 errors, [CS0106](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3dd3ha66%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and [CS0720](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/91210466%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

> C:\Path\To\Program.cs(5,23): error CS0106: The modifier 'static' is not valid for this item
>   C:\Path\To\Program\Program.cs(5,23): error CS0720: 'Fred.this[string]': cannot declare indexers in a static class

Comment: @Tom: That's okay - it happens sometimes ;)